# Prevent a notification from being blocked by the channel in Android 10

Tags: android

So I have noticed that even if I set a notification as onGoing, the user can still block the notification by swiping left or right on it and disabling the channel. Is there a way to prevent this so that the notification is truly persistent?

Comment: Thank Google that I can block your notifications on my phone if I want.

Comment: @Blundell it's a purpose build product, so it wont be on the app store.

Comment: If it's not on the appstore, you could do something hacky like changing the channelid for every notification :-)

Comment: Or, change the Android build on the hardware to not allow blocking of notifications.

Comment: @Blundell Yes, but the user would still be able to disable the notification after it shows, which is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: @MattD no, if you don't trust your users that much - change the channelId every time you show the notification. This whole idea does seem like a pointless exercise though, what's the wider use-case you are trying to achieve?